How can I map an array of objects to a Map type using DynamoDB PutItem?
This may be too complicated but here goes. I am attempting to use a StepFunction Task state to update a DynamoDB record. My input contains the following object:
{
  "importResults": {
    "result": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "description": "it failed"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "description": "it failed"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}

My state machine has a task like this:
"Update Log Table Failure":{
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "${DDBUpdateItem}",
    "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "${BuilderTable}",
        "Key": {
            "CorrelationId.$": "$.requestId"
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "set Success = :succ, Error = :err, XmlPayloadFile = :xml, ResultsFile = :res",
        "ConditionExpression": "attribute_exists($.result.result.errors)",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":succ.$": "$.result.result.success",
            ":err": {
                "M.$": {
                    "$.result.result.errors[].id": "$.result.result.errors[].description"
                }
            },
            ":xml.$": "$.result.xmlFile",
            ":res.$": "$.resultsFile"
        }
    },
    "Next": "Notify Results"
}

The question is how do I map the errors array from the input to a map type attribute? The idea would be to specify the id property as the attribute name and the description as attribute value. The other tricky part is there's no knowing how many elements are in the array of error objects. I've looked through the intrinsic functions but I don't see one that would apply to this situation. But maybe I'm not seeing something.
